# How to solve `ld: undefined reference to SSL_get_peer_certificate` in a CMake project

Tags: cmake, openssl, shared-libraries, ld, undefined-reference

I have a CMake project in Linux in which I successfully build a shared library. I will then use the library in an executable.

```
###########################
# manager SHARED LIBRARY
###########################
add_library(manager SHARED)
set_property(TARGET manager PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 17)
target_sources(manager PRIVATE "src/manager.cpp" "src/manager.h")
target_include_directories(manager PUBLIC src)
target_include_directories(manager PUBLIC ${M_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_directories(manager PUBLIC ${M_LIB_DIR})
target_link_libraries(manager PUBLIC ${M_LIB_FILES})
set_target_properties(manager PROPERTIES ENABLE_EXPORTS ON)
target_link_libraries(manager PUBLIC
        ZLIB::ZLIB
        OpenSSL::SSL OpenSSL::Crypto
)
add_library(manager::manager ALIAS manager)
# manager::manager is built successfully in both Windows and Linux

###########################
# MYAPP
########################### 
add_executable(myapp)
target_sources(myapp PRIVATE "src/main-manager.cpp")
target_link_libraries(myapp PRIVATE manager::manager)
# myapp is built successfully ONLY in Windows, it fails in Linux
```

In both Windows and Linux, I can build the shared library `manager`. However, `myapp`, which uses `manager`, is only built successfully in Windows and I get the following link errors in Linux:

```
/opt/rh/devtoolset-11/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/11/ld: lib/libmanager.so: undefined reference to `SSL_get_peer_certificate'
/opt/rh/devtoolset-11/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/11/ld: lib/libmanager.so: undefined reference to `EVP_CIPHER_iv_length'
/opt/rh/devtoolset-11/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/11/ld: lib/libmanager.so: undefined reference to `EM_put_error'
/opt/rh/devtoolset-11/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/11/ld: lib/libmanager.so: undefined reference to `EVP_PKEY_size'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/myapp.dir/build.make:120: bin/myapp] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:552: CMakeFiles/myapp.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:559: CMakeFiles/myapp.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:296: myapp] Error 2
```

All the undefined references, `SSL_get_peer_certificate`, `EVP_CIPHER_iv_length`, `EM_put_error`, `EVP_PKEY_size` belong to the OpenSSL library which is `PUBLIC`ly included in `manager` and Windows recognized this and creates `myapp.exe`, but Linux fails to do so.

Could someone kindly help me out? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Hmm, I thought I had it with `find_package`, but if the packages were not found, it wouldn't even try linking I suppose. What version of OpenSSL do you have?

Comment: I installed `OpenSSL 3.2.0` using vcpkg. The library `manager` is built successfully. Does this mean that I don't have any dependent library issues?

Comment: Since the function is found in the `ssl.h` header and it finds the libraries when linking, it seems like something is slightly off. When you build, please do it like this: `make clean && make VERBOSE=1` and include the full output from that in your question.

Comment: Since you mentioned the version of OpenSSL, I found out that `manager` only works with version 1 whereas the one installed by `vcpkg` is version 3.

Comment: Oh... :) Still odd that it doesn't find `SSL_get_peer_certificate` since that is available in OpenSSL 3.2 too.

Comment: True. `EVP_CIPHER_iv_length` does not exist in version 3 but `SSL_get_peer_certificate` exists both in version 1 and 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the looks of it, you are using old versions of `ssl.h` and `evp.h` etc.

In OpenSSL 3, `SSL_get_peer_certificate` is just a macro for `SSL_get1_peer_certificate` and `EVP_CIPHER_iv_length` is a macro for `EVP_CIPHER_get_iv_length`.

The functions it *should* try finding when linking is therefore `SSL_get1_peer_certificate` and `EVP_CIPHER_get_iv_length` - but since the old headers do not contain this mapping, it tries to find the functions by their old names inside the OpenSSL 3 library, which doesn't contain those functions.

Make sure that you use the correct header files from your `vcpkg` installation and you should be able to pass this hurdle.